# Calculate current total rolled over from previous month's balance

Tags: sql

I need a SQL query which will put the 'Current Balance' from previous month' to 'Current Total' of the next month. Attached is an image of my expected output. Please help.

I looked into LAG analytic function but could not get the desired results. I also tried using CASE statement but that is not giving expected output yet.

Here is my query:

```
select 
c.Client,
case
 when (a.CurrentTotal -isnull(b.Withdrawl,0)) > 0
 then a.CurrentTotal -isnull(b.Withdrawl,0)
 else a.CurrentTotal
end as CurrentTotal,
isnull(b.Withdrawl,0) as Withdrawl,  
case
 when b.Withdrawl > 0 
 then a.CurrentTotal -isnull(b.Withdrawl,0) -isnull(b.Withdrawl,0)
end as CurrentBalance

from CurrentTotalTable a 
left outer join WithdrawlTable b
    on a.ClientID = b.ClientID
inner join [dbo].ClientTable c
    on a.ClientID = c.ClientID

where b.WithdrawlDate between '10/1/2018' and '10/31/2018' [attached image][1]
```

Comment: Use a subquery in the column to get the amount?

Comment: BTW... your `Where` clause will turn your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. Assuming this is SQL Server.

Comment: Yes,it is SQL Server 11.0. Learning how to add a tag as I am new to this website. Thanks for your response.